# Vagrant Up Fails: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to get a server up and running on the virtual machine using Vagrant.

As soon as `vagrant up`, is executed, I get the following error for some reason.

I have bee searching for a clue for this, but have not found any useful information.

Could anyone help on this?

[System Setup]

- **OS**: Windows 10 Pro
- **Vagrant**: 2.1.1
- **VirtualBox**: 5.2

```
> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'node1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> node1: Importing base box 'centos69'...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:408:in `block in execute': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:383:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_0.rb:311:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:53:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:239:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:208:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:598:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:194:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:194:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: I think it looks like a file has been damaged. Try to uninstall and reinstall Vagrant and see if that helps.

Comment: I have freshly reinstalled Vagrant, but get the same error...

Comment: The problem most probably originates from your Vagrantfile. Can you share it please ?